# Sharepoint 2010 - feature not appearing in UI

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Does anyone here know what could cause a new feature to not show up in the SharePoint UI?
The solution it is part of has been correctly deployed to the GAC and shows up in the central administration list of deployed farm solutions, the feature appears in the FEATURES folder of the 14 hive, yet the feature itself does not appear in the features list for the site collection, either in the UI or in PowerShell using Get-SPFeature.

Yes, the feature is correctly scoped, and no, it is not hidden. :)

Any thoughts or pointers would be very welcome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer supplied on sharepoint.stackexchange.com, with thanks to Simon Doy. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73871/sharepoint-2010-feature-not-appearing-in-ui

Somehow, something had gone wrong with the installation of the feature, and neither the UI nor commands like Get-SPFeature revealed its existence, although the Install-SPFeature -ScanForFeatures command emboldened below displayed the missing feature.

> "Check that the feature has been installed. For example, if you are
>   performing Update-SPSolution and a new feature has been added between
>   solution deployments then the feature is not installed by default.
>
> To check do the following:-
>
> Run SharePoint 2010 Management Shell from one of the SharePoint
>   servers Type **Install-SPFeature -ScanForFeatures** This will show you any
>   features that are available in the SharePoint Root but have not been
>   installed. You can install any missing features using the command :-
>
> **Install-SPFeature -AllExistingFeatures** 
>   See the following TechNet
>   Article for more information.
>
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607825(v=office.14).aspx"

Answer (score 1):

Look in central admin to see what site collection the feature is deployed to.  Make sure in that site collection the feature is turned on.

Also, check the deploy job status to see if it actually finished.

Is there a on install event receiver?  If it errors out, the feature will not finish installing even after the DLL is copied.